# Check if a function parameter is the default in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, default

Lets say I have a function like this

```
function functionName(parameter = 5) {

}
```

Is it possible to check inside the function if the value of that parameter has been changed? I mean, if someone calls the function like this "functionName()" the default value wouldn't be changed but if it's called like this "functionName(10)", it's value would be different,

Comment: has this syntax been in Javascript from the beginning?

Comment: @Thilo - No, it's a new feature in ES6.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: Is that widely supported (recent browsers, node.js)?

Comment: The main purpose of using a default parameter in a function is that you DO NOT want to check whether it is changed or not, you just use it. And since default parameter always has a value, the code can safely omit the check. So, when you are performing a check that whether the value is changed or not you are indirectly violating the concept of default parameter.

Comment: @Thilo - It's supported in [recent versions of Firefox](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#default_function_params). Support for ES6 is growing quite rapidly though so keep an eye out for things like this in V8/Node soon.

Comment: But if want to know whether it is default or not, then I suggest remove the default value and check whether its `undefined` or not and if `undefined` then use 5 as default.

Comment: Unless you're willing to tell us what problem you're really trying to solve, this question simply makes no sense.  If you want to know if anything was passed as an argument, then STOP using the default assignment.  Then, you can check if the argument is `undefined` or not and if `undefined` act one way vs. if it was passed as a value.    Your whole use of the default value is messing you up.  So, either explain your real problem or stop using the default value this way.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not saying it's a good idea (if you really need to know, I'd probably just not use a default argument and check for `undefined`), but you **can** tell by looking at the `arguments` pseudo-array. Example:

```
  function myFunction(parameter = 5) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
      console.log("parameter = " + parameter + " (DEFAULT)");
    }
    else {
      console.log("parameter = " + parameter + " (provided)");
    }
  }
  myFunction();
  myFunction(5);
  myFunction(6);
```

Outputs

```
parameter = 5 (DEFAULT)
parameter = 5 (provided)
parameter = 6 (provided)
```

As you can see, you can tell if you know that `parameter` is the first argument, and `arguments.length` is `0`. Or if you had `function myFunction(a = 5, b = 6, c = 7)` you'd know `c` had been defaulted if `arguments.length` was `<= 2`.

The `arguments` section of the [draft specification](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aspecification_drafts) was until the most recent version mostly just a copy of the ES5 spec, but the April 2014 has been updated with the details of the `arguments` changes. I haven't had a chance to slog through the turgid spec-prose, but I expect this is covered in there somewhere.

[Full Live Example](http://jsbin.com/yumuboxa/1) - Only works in recent Firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Default Args</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    (function() {
      "use strict";
      function myFunction(parameter = 5) {
        if (arguments.length === 0) {
          display("parameter = " + parameter + " (DEFAULT)");
        }
        else {
          display("parameter = " + parameter + " (provided)");
        }
      }
      myFunction();
      myFunction(5);
      myFunction(6);
      function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only (efficient) way to do that is to just explicitly check for the value:

```
function functionName(parameter = 5) {
    if(parameter == 5){
        // parameter is default;
    }
}
```

Please note that optional parameters like this are not widely supported yet (It's ES6+). The "old" method would be something like this:

```
function functionName(parameter) {
    if(typeof parameter=== "undefined"){
        parameter = "defaultValue";
        // parameter is default;
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of being able to determine without a doubt if a parameter was passed or not (Unless you pass `undefined`). In the first example, a passed `5` wouldn't be distinguishable from no passed parameter.

Comment: I can't do that because the default value might change.

Comment: @Alecs - how can the default value change without you knowing it.  It's one line of code before you.  This whole question simply makes no sense.  If you want to know if a parameter was actually passed, then stop using the default parameter and then you can check whether an explicit value was passed or not.  Your use of the default value is stopping you from finding out what you want to know.

Comment: @Alecs: What about my 2nd suggestion? Also, if the default value changes, you can just change it in the `if`, too, right?

Comment: What does _"not working"_ mean? What __is__ happening, and what do you __expect__ to happen?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Guess what? There *is* a way to check! I thought there might be, but first I had to grab the latest draft spec and update Firefox on my Windows 8.1 machine... :-) Details in my answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yea, I saw your solution, nifty! It's disappointing that the OP doesn't seem to know what it is he wants, though. Apparently all he wanted was a way to pass default parameters, looking at the accepted answer.

Comment: @ Cerbrus - Even then, this is a much better answer than the [currently-accepted one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23382439/157247), to *both* questions -- what the OP actually asked, and what it may be he/she wanted. @Alecs: Seriously, the `typeof parameter === "undefined"` check Cerbrus showed you is the better way to do this. `||` is nice for some things, but it can't be used for a numeric arg unless `0` isn't a valid value to pass in. (Similarly, not for strings unless `""` isn't a valid value to pass in.) `||` is mostly nice when you're expecting an object. Otherwise, check for undefined.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Those "seen" values are wildly wrong most of the time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a default value in case no parameter was passed?

```
    function myFunction(parameter) {

        parameter = parameter || 5;
    }
```

Or you could access the arguments variable to check the parameter better.

Comment: And if `0` is a valid value for `parameter`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Whoa o.O ... I never realized that. Not that I use default parameters that often, but `||` is out of the window. Any way, -1 because this question isn't about _"How do I use default parameters"_, rather _"How do I check if a parameter is passed"_

Comment: It's working but I think I have to change a few things in my code because this isn't really what I need. 
Noobie things, I guess. Thanks, i'll mark it as good answer.

Comment: this was supposed to be a basic example. If 0 counts as well there has to be a more precise check of cause.

Comment: @Alecs: How does this answer the question you asked? This is just a basic (and apparently broken) way of using default parameters.

Comment: It didn't, my mistake. Anyway, I expected a build in function to check if the value is the default or not and as I see, it doesn't exists.

Comment: @Alecs: Then does T.J's, or my answer come close to answering your question? I realize a "Nope, not possible" is not what you're looking for, but it may be the right answer.